# Android: Does geofence automatically update the user position?

Tags: android, google-api, geofencing, android-geofence

From what I know, the Google API Geofence should automatically retrieve the location of the device based on some parameters (e.g. the distance from the area). However, I've been trying to implement the code provided [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#CreateAdd) and run it on the virtual machine for several minutes, but the current location of the device is never updated.

So, it is not clear to me if the Geofence automatically and periodically retrieves the location of the device, or simply uses the last known location.

Comment: As far as I know, non-physical runtime environments, e.g. the emulators (is this what you mean by "virtual machine"?) do not have GPS capabilities, and can only change their current location when you manually set it.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I just tested it on a physical device (with a minimum radius of 100 meters as indicated in the guide) and it works correctly.